# Windows Forms: Best way to store table lookups

Tags: windows, forms, c#-4.0

Developing new C# .net4.5 Windows Forms application.  I want to code it "right".  I'm developing a couple User Controls.  The controls are shared via several tabs.  On the controls are some common drop down boxes that are populated with the same SQL Server table data. (one or two columns)  I want to read the DB once and have the lookup data available during the entire user experience.  The app will be used by many users.  Whats the best way to store this data in my new code? example code appreciated.  cache?  static list ?   Help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply a global `DataTable (Dataset)` would do.  Or if you want control over the contents of the list using `SortedDictionary` containing your own custom class for each row would suffice.

The Custom Class is a tidy way of holding a cache (for the data you want from each row), as you can override the `ToString` function and populate the user controls easily.

To share this cache amongst many users is not easy, and could prove more trouble than its worth.  Each user with a separate copy of the program would have their own copy of the cache (in the 2 methods above).  (But the user controls will also contains subsets of this cache too).  And each program would need to load the user controls, so perhaps this sharing across multiple instances direction is moot.